# Analytics regular expression – identify string in url as goal

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am looking to set up a goal in analytics to record people submitting an information pack form.

The destination page will look something like this   www.domainname.com/info/product/campaign-name/ipcthankyou/

The /product/ and /campaign-name/ will change throughout the site. They may even be in further folders down the line. All I wish to track is if someone went to the /ipcthankyou/ section.

It maybe that there are pages within the /ipcthankyou/ section e.g. it url may look like www.domainname.com/info/product/campaign-name/ipcthankyou/information

So far, I am using    `^/ipcthankyou`   however this does not seem to work. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^/ipcthankyou` will only find strings that BEGIN with "/ipcthankyou". Well, actually it will fail because the `/` needs to be escaped as so: `\/`

What you'll want is something that looks more like `^.+\/ipcthankyou` which will match any characters before the "/ipcthankyou" and then the "/ipcthankyou" part.

To get the entire URL then simply follow it with another `.+` to match everything afterwards: `^.+\/ipcthankyou.+`

Comment: ok great thanks. If I go with this way, will I also be able to have information after the /ipcthankyou/ as well? e.g. /ipcthankyou/page1.php or /ipcthankyou/thanks/thankyou.php   ?

Comment: I've edited it to add another .+ at the end to match the whole URL containing "/ipcthankyou".

Comment: ok great... i have just added this in, i have verified it and all seems to be looking ok so far. Lets just hope this will work over time. thanks!